# How to force a mob to rotate towards the player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a command that will cause a mob to rotate towards the nearest player. Instantly would be preferable, but I'll do whatever works. I know you can set rotation of a mob if you tp it, but I need a way to set the rotation so that it faces the nearest player. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work on PC, but this works on MCPE:

`tp @e[type=!Player,type=!Item] ~~~ facing @p`

The problem is that it will stay on its position until moved, but it will always face you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `/execute @e[type =1tp @e[type=!player]`